# Accents in \label and \ref arguments

Tags: accents

I'd like to know how to include words with accents in `\label{}` and `\ref{}` arguments.

For example : `\label{Molécules d'immunoglobulines}`
`\ref{Molécules d'immunoglobulines}`

I've already succeeded giving file names with spaces and accents to the argument command `\includegraphics{}` thanks to the package `grffile`, but I can't find an easy way to do it with `\label{}` and `\ref{}` commands. Do you have any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: It is best to consider that argument to be the same as a tex command and use the same syntax restrictions just a-zA-Z0-9 and ascii punctuation.  It is possible to make more work but it adds no extra functionality and is rather fragile

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - It may be worth pointing out that the "a-zA-Z0-9 and ascii punctuation" restriction applies to pdfLaTeX (and even older engines/formats). XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are not affected by this restriction.

Comment: @Mico they do work, but I think as a matter of definition of latex as a language that doesn't mean that they are valid and should be used.

Answer (score 9):

The key for `\label` and `\ref` consists of ASCII letters, digits, and punctuation (LaTeX Companion, 2ed).

Package `babel` does some hacking to allow its shorthands.

The `key` is internally used to create a command `\r@<key>` via `\csname`. This can be broken by anything, which is not a character or does not expand to a letter. Accented letters quite often breaks this, depending on their implementation (packages `inputenc`, `fontenc`), examples:

- Font encoding `OT1` (default in LaTeX2e) does not have slots for the accented characters, thus is implementation uses the `\accent` primitive, which cannot be used in `\csname`.
- The font encoding `T1` has slots, thus it might work, e.g.:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \begin{document}
  \section{Hello World}
  \label{Molécules d'immunoglobulines}
  \ref{Molécules d'immunoglobulines}
  \end{document}
  ```

  The `.aux` file contains:

  ```
  \newlabel{Mol\IeC {\'e}cules d'immunoglobulines}{{1}{1}}
  ```

  The simple example works with this for of the accented letter, but there is no grantee that this works with all packages.
- Best for accented characters are LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, when the accented characters are also ordinary letters at TeX level, because these TeX engines are capable of Unicode.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that accented characters are no big deal when working with XeLaTeX and/or LuaLaTeX.